# Python-requests : how do I check if a user already logged in or not?

Tags: python, python-2.7, authentication, python-requests

I'm writing a simple Python program using only requests module.

```
s = requests.Session()
#if a user is already logged in, then execute next statement
r = s.get(url)  #or r = s.get(url,data=data) In general
else
#ask user to provide valid login credentials and use s.post(url,data=data,headers=headers)
#and update session
```

so my question is how can I check If a provided user credentials are of user's which is already logged in?

Comment: can you expand a little on what ````#and update session```` means. What code are you running there? The way that you log a user in has a bearing on how you check that a user is logged in.

Answer (score 2):

You have access to `s.cookies` which should contain all of your session values. To check if a user is logged in you just need to check a session value using something like

```
if 'userid' in s.cookies:
    r = s.get(url, data=data)
else:
    .....
```

Which would be set when the user logs in. (roughly equivalent to PHP's: `isset($_SESSION['userid'])`)

Note I say `'userid'` but what I really mean is the key that corresponds to any session value that is only set upon user login which could be `'user'`, `'username'`, `'id'` etc...